# Image size is big but the font is pixelated in TV

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My image size is 3128*1916. I open the image in 55" inch TV and the image font is pixelated. I also try to change the dpi but it's not showing properly.

Comment: 55": which resolution? how are you connecting to this TV (HDMI, DVI, PC, chromecast...)? What software are you using to display your image on the TV? Can you [edit] your question to add more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Stop. Forget all together DPI, PPI. You do not need those values on an electronic device.

The device has only one resolution, the native resolution. Is the TV Full HD 1920x1080px? or 4K in some special flavor. Let us assume it is the normal 4K 3840 x 2160 px.

As your image does not match any of those resolutions, it is most likely rescaled. How this image is rescaled is unknown, there are a lot of ways it can be done.

---

My recommendation is

1. Find out the native resolution of your TV.
2. Prepare a canvas of that same exact size. Resample your image and put it there.

---

Some more variables would be how are you showing your image. Are you connecting a PC using HDMI? are you plugging a USB stick and using some program inside the TV? Are you streaming it?

There can be a problem somewhere else. So check these variables.